# Where to find the Bulgarian embassy in Uganda?

Tags: visas, applications, bulgaria, ugandan-citizens

I'm a Ugandan citizen who needs to apply for a Bulgarian visit visa. I don't know where to apply as we don't have a Bulgarian embassy in Uganda. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you can, you should probably wait until March 31st, when Bulgaria joins Schengen, as this could make things easier.

Comment: Thanks so much . I will wait

Answer (score 23):

According to the [Bulgarian Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.mfa.bg/en/embassyinfo/uganda), Bulgarian consular affairs in Uganda are handled by [the embassy in Addis Ababa, Ethiopia](https://www.mfa.bg/en/embassies/ethiopia). You should contact them for further information about the process for applying for a visa there.

However, Bulgaria [is set to join](https://www.euronews.com/travel/2024/03/20/bulgaria-and-romania-join-schengen-experts-on-what-it-will-mean-for-prices-transport-overt) the [schengen](/questions/tagged/schengen) area on March 31, 2024. From this point, there will be a procedure to apply for short-stay visas valid for Bulgaria at the embassy (or outsourced visa-processing company) of another EU country in Kampala. So, if it is practical for you to delay your trip a bit, it might save you the trouble of communicating with the embassy in Addis Ababa.

Comment: It's not clear to me that the Addis Ababa embassy actually handles visa applications from foreign citizens; unless I've missed something, the linked page only talks about how it provides consular services for Bulgarian citizens in Uganda.  But I agree that the OP should contact them; even if they don't handle such applications themselves, they would know who does.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert yeah, I agree. I can't figure out if it's just a poorly-worded webpage or they in fact do not handle visa applications. But if you contact them, they surely know the answer.

Answer (score -2):

I would [try to contact](https://www.mfa.bg/en/embassyinfo/uganda) the Ugandan consulate in Bulgaria or the Embassy in Berlin (Germany).

Sometimes these things are sorted out per physical mail and you may be more lucky with appliyng directly in the destination "political area" rather than the departure one.

Comment: How could a Ugandan consulate or embassy help with an application for a visa for Bulgaria?

Comment: Because OP would like to apply for a visit visa, which is a short-term visa, which is a Schengen visa and they may know the best way to obtain a Schengen visa for a person from the same nation.
Bulgaria will not issue Schengen visa until the 01. April 2024, but due to the peculiarity of Bulgaria in Europe I am quite sure that contacting any Uganda consulate in Germany (Europe) is more useful than asking random people on the internet.

Comment: @EarlGrey That doesn't make much sense. If a person X lives in Germany, has a German nationality and wants to obtain visa for the USA, they must contact a US consulate in Germany, not a German consulate in the USA!

Comment: "they must contact a US consulate in Germany" then go and contact a bulgarian consulate in Uganda

Comment: I contacted the ugandan consulate in bulgaria i'm waiting for the response on monday . Thanks

Comment: @EarlGrey Right, the point is that there is no Bulgarian consulate in Uganda, hence the question about who to contact instead. But a Ugandan consulate definitely can't issue Bulgarian visas, so that doesn't seem like the best people to contact.

Comment: You might as well contact your email provider to ask who to email.

Comment: @EarlGrey I know there's no Bulgarian consulate in Uganda. So you must contact the right one in Ethiopia. An Ugandan consulate in Bulgaria has no authority to issue a Bulgarian / Schengen visa for you!

Comment: @Johnnyjanko "So you must contact the right one in Ethiopia." yes, sure, which one is the right one? nowhere in the bulgarian consulate in Ethipoia page they say they care for Ugandan citizen needs. And ugandan consulates/embassies are much more likely to know the procedures for their own citizens than random commenters on internet like you, which makes useless parallel with US state of law, while Europe is more akin to "apply for Visa Schengen to Texas, then you may be able to visit Alaska". And you can get Schengen visa with middlemen, not only with official gov't & embassies.

Comment: @EarlGrey no, you're completely wrong. Ugandan consulate in Bulgaria can help Ugandan citizens if they are already in Bulgaria and have for example lost their passport or got into some legal trouble (among other things). They won't help you to get a Bulgarian visa. Other people have already posted the correct answer (to contact a BG consulate in Ethiopia) so this is all pointless.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko the *correct answer* is just a rumour, because the BG consulate in Ethiopia mentions they will help Bulgarian in Uganda, but it says nothing about Ugandan people. "The Republic of Bulgaria does not have a functioning embassy in Kampala, the capital of Uganda. **Bulgarian citizens residing in Uganda** on a short or long-term basis may address consular matters to the Embassy of the Republic of Bulgaria in Addis Ababa, Ethiopia." 
You are welcome. To step out of your self-righteous attitude.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko but I still give +1 for your comments because they are really helpful. In understanding you!

Comment: @EarlGrey If you contact the BG embassy in Ethiopia, the *might* tell you to apply for a BG visa somewhere else. So far so good. Here's a map of Bulgarian embassies: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Diplomatic_missions_of_Bulgaria.PNG But contacting a Ugandan embassy in BG is not going to help at all. Based on the downvotes, it's not just my self-righteous attitude.

Comment: @EarlGrey it's great when my comments help you to understand me. But I'd be happier if they helped you understand the problem I'm writing about.